# How to create database automatically using hibernate with struts 2 framework (Bootstrap file)?

Tags: hibernate, struts2, struts

Is there any kind of bootstrap file in struts framework, where the file runs only a single time when it gets started first time. Because I need to insert some default values in database when app runs first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Is there any kind of bootstrap file in struts framework?

A: No. (Not without doing something atypical at least... although I think there is room for adding a feature for struts2 to do this in a prescribed way)

However at a slightly higher level (the Java EE environment) you can do what you need with a ServletContextListener, for an example of use see: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/